# Othello - Validating player moves

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array, game-development

I'm in the process of making a recreation of Othello/Reversi with the use of a 2D Array. For each grid space I have a value stored in it("Black", "White" or ""). From there, I code what should and shouldn't be a legal move by the standards of the game rules. The problem is that it's difficult for me to understand how to translate the rules to code. How would any of you translate Othello's rules into a 2D Array based game.

I'm relatively new to coding and haven't had luck with trying to translate source code as this project needs to be my own VB.net 2010 coding, any advice helps.

I've tried everything from long if/elseif statements, many 2D loops, even a separate array that was supposed to validate moves itself. Nothing I've tried has been able to make it past the first move without breaking in some way.

Comment: You'll need to provide some sample code here. Maybe the rules for the game you're trying to recreate along with the code that you've written that isn't working and you're struggling with

Comment: *How would any of you translate these rules into a 2D array based game?*  is too broad and vague. This site is for **specific questions** related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool. Include the code you've written and ask a specific question related to that code. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: VS 2010 is ancient at this point; VS 2022 is free for personal use, is there a particular reason you want to use an obsolete version of the IDE?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Have some pseudocode. No idea what programming language that is supposed to be, I made it up on the spot.

```
is_valid_move(x,y,color): {
  if (board[x,y] != empty) return false;
  for dx = -1 to 1: {
    for dy = -1 to 1: { // cycle through all directions
      if (dx=0 && dy=0) next;
      xx = x+dx; yy = y+dy;
      while (valid_coords(xx, yy) && board[xx, yy]=enemy(color)): {
      // skipping over enemy stones, there has to be at least one

        xx = xx+dx; yy = yy+dy;
        if (valid_coords(xx, yy) && board[xx, yy]=color)
          return true; // this one is ours, we have captured something
      }
    }
  }
  return false; // no capture found, this is not a valid move
}
```